# EntityFrameworkCore Using ToTable for not default name of Entity does not create Table in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have faced with issue using Entity Framework Core and Npgsql NuGet Package for PostgresSQL that when I try to create table for not default Entity name I got error message:

```
Relation "Usersss" does not exist
```

Below proper code which create in database table Users:

```
    public class PosgresSQLDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        private string _ipAddress;
        private short _port;

        public PosgresSQLDBContext(string ipAddress = "localhost", short port = 5432)
        {
            _ipAddress = ipAddress;
            _port = port;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql($"Host={_ipAddress};Port={_port};Database=learningef;Username=postgres;Password=postgres");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Description of User
            modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("users_id_seq");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Users", "public");
                entity.HasKey(u => u.Id);
                entity.Property(u => u.Id)
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)");
            });
        }
    }
```

But if I change only name of table like this:

```
    public class PosgresSQLDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        private string _ipAddress;
        private short _port;

        public PosgresSQLDBContext(string ipAddress = "localhost", short port = 5432)
        {
            _ipAddress = ipAddress;
            _port = port;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql($"Host={_ipAddress};Port={_port};Database=learningef;Username=postgres;Password=postgres");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Description of User
            modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("users_id_seq");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Usersss", "public");
                entity.HasKey(u => u.Id);
                entity.Property(u => u.Id)
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)");
            });
        }
    }
```

then I got the error:

```
Relation "Usersss" does not exist
```

I cannot get why ? Because according the documentation it should work ... But it does not ...

Have anybody faced with such issue ?

Comment: Well, just changing a `ToTable` call doesn't change the table name in the database. To get that done you have to add a migration.

Comment: @GertArnold Seems like you are right ... I have deleted old table and restarted application and it have created Usersss table properly ... but I did not get ... How Entity know that I am creating the same table as in privious time ... I mean maybe I have completly different data ? Does it know it by Entity Class Name ?

Comment: @GertArnold If you answer this question I will mark it as answer